# WordPress delete checkout button from cart widget

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming

I want to delete the checkout button from the cart widget so that a user has to view their cart first and can only checkout from the cart page.

[image]

I am sure I have to delete some code somewhere but not sure where.

Comment: Can you be more specific? What plugin are you using for the shop? Which theme are you using? What have you already tried?

Comment: am using woo commerce and the theme is Starbella. I've tried the CSS code in the comments below also the woo commerce hook, none have worked. @chillichief

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways you can achieve this.

The first method is to remove the button using the Woocommerce Hook. Add the below code in your functions.php file

```
  function my_woocommerce_widget_shopping_cart_proceed_to_checkout() 
    {
        return;
    }
    add_action( 'woocommerce_widget_shopping_cart_buttons', 

'my_woocommerce_widget_shopping_cart_proceed_to_checkout', 20 );
```

Another method is by using the CSS to hide that particular button.

Add display: none to that specific button by identifying its class.

```
.woocommerce-mini-cart__buttons .checkout.wc-forward {display: none !important;}
```

Comment: Can you share the URL\Link of the website? Need to find the class/id selector for exact code

Comment: I have updated my answer with new CSS. This one should work. So add the updated CSS in your stylesheet and see if it works.

Comment: Upvote the answer so it will be useful for others too.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by using the css or need to check your code to find and remove the button. If you are using the plugin then please check for the hook you are using and edit that one.

With the CSS, you can easily hide the checkout button.

Use it like

```
.widget_sidebar .checkout_button {
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a mini cart you can try this

```
 add_action( 'woocommerce_widget_shopping_cart_buttons', 
 'woocommerce_widget_shopping_cart_proceed_to_checkout', 20 );
```

If you are using some plugin then let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You can hide the checkout button multiple ways
1) With Hook

```
function widget_checkoutbutton() 
{
    return;
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_widget_shopping_cart_buttons','widget_checkoutbutton', 20 );
```

2) With CSS
Identify the class name of checkout button and write display none with root class.